# how to return to back to the full screen in javafx after press ESC to exit full screen mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I want to make the function to return to the full-screen mode after pressing ESC to exit the full-screen mode.

Is there any method to return to full-screen?

for example,
to execute the full screen mode, I used the method as below

```
@Override
public void init(Controller controller) {
    sound.backgroundMusic();
    menuButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    createSubScenes(controller);
    createButtons(controller);
    createBackground();
    createLogo();
    controller.setScene(mainScene);

}

public void setScene(Scene scene) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> stage.setScene(scene));
    Platform.runLater(() -> stage.setFullScreen(true));
}
```

in the stage, when I press ESC, the stage exits to the full screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUpiN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH3qq.png)

and then in this stage, I want to hope to return to the full screen mode.

Comment: `stage.setFullScreen(true)`?

Comment: I mean.. when I press ESC, and then how to make the full screen mode again?

Comment: still don't understand: what do you want to achieve? and what exactly is the problem? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: does it make sense?

Comment: @kleopatra nvm, I fixed that. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent from going out of full-screen with *ESC* (or any other key) using:

```
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
```

If you are not in full-screen, create a *listener* or *method* to go to full-screen executing:

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```